# Error running google-cloud-sdk on gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to have google datastore emulator run as part of the CI. I've added a `services` section to `.gitlab-ci.yml` but there's an error.

Here's the full configuration YAML:

```yaml
image: python:3.9-slim

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip

variables:
  DATASTORE_DATASET: project-007
  DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: google-cloud-sdk:8081
  DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH: google-cloud-sdk:8081/datastore
  DATASTORE_HOST: http://google-cloud-sdk:8081
  DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID: project-007

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg make 
  - python --version  # Print out python version for debugging
  - cd backend
  - python -m pip install -r dev-requirements.txt

test:
  services:
    - name: google/cloud-sdk:latest
      command: ["gcloud", "beta", "emulators", "datastore", "start", "--host-port", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
      variables:
        CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT: project-007
  script:
    - make test
```

The error I see in the CI logs is:

```
*** WARNING: Service runner--azerasq-project-26594908-concurrent-0-aababf5d82e87691-google__cloud-sdk-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner--azerasq-project-26594908-concurrent-0-aababf5d82e87691-google__cloud-sdk-0-wait-for-service" health check: exit code 1
Health check container logs:
2021-11-25T15:49:31.057994970Z FATAL: No HOST or PORT found                      
Service container logs:
2021-11-25T15:49:30.783697828Z Executing: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator create --project_id=gitlab-ci-plan-free-5-6ef84d /root/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore
*********
```

Any ideas how to fix this or a better way to run the datastore emulator in the gitlab CI?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the emulator runs correctly when you run `docker run -it -e CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=test google/cloud-sdk:latest gcloud beta emulators datastore start --host-port 0.0.0.0:8080`, it's not a problem with your container command. That means that it's an issue within GitLab's runner setup, or within the way that you're using the runner setup. [Specifically, how the services health check works](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#how-the-health-check-of-services-works).

The issue you're seeing is that the `google/cloud-sdk` image has no PORT exposed, because it's meant to be an CLI (not a web app) and the act of exposing a port is a byproduct of the emulator. This means that the services health check can't find a port to check for the container health, and instantly fails. To resolve this issue, simply build your own image based on the SDK, and expose port 8080, as such:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk
EXPOSE 8080
```

then update your services block to use that container instead:

```
  services:
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      alias: google-test
      command: ["gcloud", "beta", "emulators", "datastore", "start", "--host-port", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
      variables:
        CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT: project-007
```

and your service will now pass healthcheck appropriately. Here is the output from my test in a gitlab repo:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.4.0-rc1 (bc99a056)
  on blue-5.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default -AzERasQ
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 01:26
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Starting service registry.gitlab.com/patrick/service-test:latest ...
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/patrick/service-test:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:954ea7f75a0a88b281d46cbaa1c359e0782268a6c5390a722ebea387893e7a47 for registry.gitlab.com/patrick/service-test:latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/patrick/service-test@sha256:8d240acba0977cc8deea217026d23678e471a5453ffd4dbeeb4197aa1b6e024d ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:c059bfaa849c4d8e4aecaeb3a10c2d9b3d85f5165c66ad3a4d937758128c4d18 for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:21a3deaa0d32a8057914f36584b5288d2e5ecc984380bc0118285c70fa8c9300 ...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner--azerasq-project-31673063-concurrent-0 via runner-azerasq-shared-1638120050-4cf20e79...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/patrick/service-test/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out a4825851 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:c059bfaa849c4d8e4aecaeb3a10c2d9b3d85f5165c66ad3a4d937758128c4d18 for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:21a3deaa0d32a8057914f36584b5288d2e5ecc984380bc0118285c70fa8c9300 ...
$ ping google-test
PING google-test (172.17.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
```

Comment: Hello @lazy1, please remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out once I'm back from vacation

Comment: Thanks for the details answer, I have integration testing now!